# Batch - Extract variables from specific word or string

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I need to extract 4 variables (`VAR1`, `VAR2`, `VAR3`, `VAR4`) from a specific string.

For example, I have many strings with `12` characters looks like:

P**02**L**96**C**06**S**09**

and I need to set:

1. `VAR1`=`02` (characters at positions `2` and `3`)
2. `VAR2`=`96` (characters at positions `5` and `6`)
3. `VAR3`=`06` (characters at postions `8` and `9`)
4. `VAR4`=`09` (characters at postions `11` and `12`)

Note: the number of characters never changes. There are always `12`, and their pattern is always in the format:

- ```
  P[0-9][0-9]L[0-9][0-9]C[0-9][0-9]S[0-9][0-9]
  ```

The source strings will be retrieved from a file, `AAA.txt`, where each will reside one a separate line.

Comment: From the prompt, type `set /?` and enter. This will show you documentation. Assuming that your 12-character string is in a vatiable called `string` then `set "var1=%string:~1,2%` will set `var1` for you; `set "var2=%string:~3,2%` will set `var2` and so on.

Comment: Please delete the above comment @GianlucaBarbacci. I have, as you should have done, [Edit]ed your question to update it with that information. Once done, I will return here myself to delete this comment too.